# Promises inside nested loops

Tags: promise, nosql

I have a query to a NoSQL database. Since in this type of database there are not many options for complex queries, I need to make two nested queries to other tables within a loop

created by the first query. Using promises, I decided to read the first nested query. However, the whole block is not "waiting" for the most internal query, and the results it brings

(from users) are not being counted. Here is the simplified code:

The block does the following: For each room (outermost loop), it reads all messages (first promise, from messageRef) and, for each message, takes the user data (second promise, from

usersRef). The first nested query is ok (brings up all messages). However, the user data for each message is not being loaded (in this case, I just put the name, for simplicity).

The messageRef and usersRef objects return promises that are stored in the promises array. At the end, when all are finalized (Promise.all), it returns the array with all the data.

Each "obj" object has the data of each room. In obj.messages, it has the array of message objects and, at each obj.messages, the user data.

```
roomRef.on('value', function(data){
    var promises = [],
        threads = [],
        counter = 0;
    $.each(data.val(), function(id, obj){
        obj.id = id;
        obj.messages = [];
        var promise = messageRef.child(id).on('child_added', function(data){
            var msgobj = data.val();
            obj.messages.push(msgobj);
            return usersRef.orderByChild('login').equalTo(msgobj.createdBy.login).once('child_added', function(data){
                msgobj.createdBy.name = data.val().name;
            });
        });
        promises.push(promise);
        threads[counter] = obj;
        counter += 1;
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
        console.log(threads) // array with all data
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query then use query not a event callback child_added.

child_added callback isn't return promise. It triggered when data added. change them to query that return promise.

```
roomRef.on('value', function(data) {
  var promises = [],
  $.each(data.val(), function(id, obj) {
    obj.id = id
    obj.messages = []

    var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      messageRef.child(id).on('child_added', function(data) {
        var msgobj = data.val()
        obj.messages.push(msgobj)
        usersRef
          .orderByChild('login')
          .equalTo(msgobj.createdBy.login)
          .once('child_added', function(data) {
            msgobj.createdBy.name = data.val().name
            resolve(msgobj)
          })
      })
    })
    promises.push(promise)
  })
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(threads) {
    console.log(threads) // array with all data
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Is that firebase database? why you are using child_added

Comment: I edited for some example please try it. hope it helps.

Comment: I will try it. Soon I give a feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Obba, thanks for your help, but it still is not working. Only a few names are being loaded. All names are loaded correctly just when I force a waiting in:
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            onComplete(threads);
        }, 1000);
    });

Which is, in fact, not correct (since query time may vary depending on the number of users). Any idea? Thanks!